# Proving that one can integrate a uniformly convergent series of functions term by term

Tags: complex-analysis

I aim to understand the following proof from Serge Lang's Introduction to Complex Analysis at a graduate level

[[image: Theorem1]

and I have the following definitions

[image: Definition 1]
[image: Definition 2]

My question is: What does the last paragraph of the theorem in question actually mean? Does it mean that every $f_i$ is convergent, and if yes, how is this derived from the definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last paragraph means that if for each $n$ we set
$$
s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n f_k,
$$
then the sequence $(s_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges uniformly on $U$ to $s:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k$. Then, by the first part of the Theorem
$$
\lim_n\int_{\gamma} s_n = \int_\gamma s
$$
which translates as
$$
\lim_n\int_{\gamma} \sum_{k=1}^n f_k = \int_\gamma \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k
$$
and since
$$
\lim_n\int_{\gamma} \sum_{k=1}^n f_k =\lim_n   \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\gamma}f_k =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\gamma}  f_k 
$$
the desired result follows.

Comment: thanks for the asnwer. I have two questions. 1) Does it mean that for each $n$ we have $s_n$ uniformaly convergent (and is this from the definition above or a derived result)? 2) When you interchange the integral and sumation aren't you already using the result of what you are trying to prove?

Comment: You're welcome! (1) Each $s_n$ is a function so it doesn't make sense to say that a function is uniformly convergent. However, $(s_n)_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions that converges uniformly to $s$. (2) At the very last line when I exchanged the limit with the sum, notice that the sum is **finite**, so $\int \sum_1^n = \sum_1^n\int$ by linearity of the integral. The result proves that you can still perform this exchange for the **infinite sum** case provided that you have uniform convergence. Hope that this answers your questions.

Comment: Hi @Alonso Delfín , thank you very much for your answer. One final thing, for a sequence to be uniformly convergent is it required for every term to be convergent( or maybe in the complex numbers absolutely convergent)?

Comment: What do exactly do you mean for every term to be convergent? By definition a sequence $(g_n)_n$ of functions on $U$ is uniformly convergent if $\| g_n -g \|_\infty \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. In particular this implies pointwise convergence, that is for any $z \in U$, $|g_n(z)-g(z)| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. In other words, if $g_n \to g$ uniformly, then $g_n(z) \to g(z)$ for each $z \in U$.

Comment: Hi @Alonso Delfín, I didn't express my self correctly. What I meant is, does the uniform convergence of a sequence $(g_n)_n$ imply that each term is well defined or only the limit term?

Comment: Sure, in any sequence $(g_n)_n$, each $g_n$ is a well defined function; doesn’t matter if the sequence converges or not.

Answer (score 1):

"$\sum_n f_n$ is a series of continuous functions converging uniformly on $\Omega$"
means each $f_n$ is a continuous function on $\Omega$, and the series $\sum_n f_n$ converges uniformly on $\Omega$.